# REGEXP to group a single FULL NAME String with one or more spaces in between?

Tags: regex, oracle, substring, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am pulling some data from my DB. The values is **NAME**. The Db pulls the Results as follows:

```
RAMIREZ------RODRIGUEZ------JUAN----P
RAMIREZ-RODRIGUEZ------JUAN----P
RAMIREZ-RODRIGUEZ------JUAN----P--
RAMIREZ-RODRIGUEZ-JUAN-P
```

----- = blank spaces

I been using https://regexr.com/ but I having a hard time understanding some of the concepts and how to build the expression.

What I need is a regular expression that will Group me the FULL NAME in three sections (lastname, firstname, middlename). I already have my query:

```
//I am doing the last part out of order because as you can see the DB pulls the names out of order and 
//I am using three groups taking Ramirez Rodriguez as LASTNAME/ JUAN as first name/ P as middle name
// As you will see in the examples sometimes it has two last names like in the example they can be separated by 1 blank space or can be separated by more than 1
REGEXP_SUBSTR(name, '(desires reg exp)', 1,2) //First name
REGEXP_SUBSTR(name, '(desires reg exp)', 1,1) //middle name
REGEXP_SUBSTR(name, '(desires reg exp)', 1,3) //last name
```

I think I have found the solution for when it has more than two blank spaces between names
[image: REGEXP for more than two blank spaces between names and spaces after middle name]

The same expression works when the middle name at the doesn't have any spaces at the end which was one of my main issues before

[image: REG EXP with more than two blank space in between names and no spaces at the end]

For this I want to know if I did it correctly and if you can explain why it works because I am still confused on how the expression evaluates  the string

THE MAIN ISSUE IS THIS REG EXP doesnt work when the full name is like so:

```
RAMIREZ-RODRIGUEZ-JUAN-P
RAMIREZ-RODRIGUEZ-JUAN-P-
```

I haven't been able to build it

Long post but hope you can help, sorry for bad subject, couldnt come with a better one

Answer (score 1):

For splitting words, you can use the *n*th occurrence of pattern `[^ ]+` (one or more non-space characters).

```sql
with test (str) as
     ( select column_value
       from   ora_mining_varchar2_nt
              ( 'RAMIREZ      RODRIGUEZ      JUAN    P'
              , 'RAMIREZ RODRIGUEZ      JUAN    P'
              , 'RAMIREZ RODRIGUEZ      JUAN    P  '
              , 'RAMIREZ RODRIGUEZ JUAN P'
              , 'RAMIREZ RODRIGUEZ JUAN P ' ) )
select str
     , regexp_substr(str,'[^ ]+', 1, 1) as last_name
     , regexp_substr(str,'[^ ]+', 1, 2) as first_name
     , regexp_substr(str,'[^ ]+', 1, 3) as middle_name
     , regexp_substr(str,'[^ ]+', 1, 4) as middle_initial
from   test;
```

```
STR                                    LAST_NAME   FIRST_NAME  MIDDLE_NAME  MIDDLE_INITIAL
-------------------------------------- ----------- ----------- ------------ --------------
RAMIREZ      RODRIGUEZ      JUAN    P  RAMIREZ     RODRIGUEZ   JUAN         P
RAMIREZ RODRIGUEZ      JUAN    P       RAMIREZ     RODRIGUEZ   JUAN         P
RAMIREZ RODRIGUEZ      JUAN    P       RAMIREZ     RODRIGUEZ   JUAN         P
RAMIREZ RODRIGUEZ JUAN P               RAMIREZ     RODRIGUEZ   JUAN         P
RAMIREZ RODRIGUEZ JUAN P               RAMIREZ     RODRIGUEZ   JUAN         P
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but this is not what I asked i know how to split each string. My question is clearly stated above on how to build a reg exp similar to mi examples to know how to group each name as stated. Ramirez Rodriguez group. Juan another group and P another group. So when i get my query result is Juan P Ramirez Rodriguez. Using only three regexp in the query

Comment: Perhaps if you can explain your requirement clearly with examples and not screenshots someone will be able to help you.